# Ошибка в создании ImageLoader

Tags: android, activity, universal-image-loader

Добавил код как пишет здесь http://nostra13android.blogspot.com/2012/03/5-universal-image-loader-part-2.html , и возникает ошибка: подкреслено красным `ImageView imageView = "mImg1";` и пишет `Incompatible types. Required: android.widget.ImageView Found: java.lang.String` поменял на `ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImg1);` но все равно картинка не показывается!

```
// Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this config
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
            mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


        ImageView imageView = "mImg1"; // <-- ошибка здесь!! вьюха, где будет отображать картинку
        String imageUrl = "http://тут.мой.сайт/image.png"; // URL картинки (н-р: "http://site.com/image.png", "file:///mnt/sdcard/img/image.jpg")

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Получили экземпляр
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this)); // Проинициализировали конфигом по умолчанию
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView); // Запустили асинхронный показ картинки
```

Comment: Т.е. ваша проблема решена?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет картинка не отображается(((

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Зачем так муторно все делаешь, на улице 21 век, есть библиотека Picasso самая лучшая, ничего не надо. Пишешь 1 строчку Url и все, картинка загружается в кэш. Читай про пикассо и ты увидишь до чего она проста в использовании.